# How can I get the row id from this object?

Tags: node.js

From my cassandra I get this data and want to display the rows but how can I retrieve the row id?

```
ResultSet {
  info: {
    queriedHost: '0.0.0.0:9042',
    triedHosts: { '0.0.0.0:9042': null },
    speculativeExecutions: 0,
    achievedConsistency: 6,
    traceId: undefined,
    warnings: undefined,
    customPayload: undefined,
    isSchemaInAgreement: true
  },
  rows: [ Row { id: 1, name: 'John' } ],
  rowLength: 1,
  columns: [ { name: 'car_make', type: [Object] } ],
  pageState: null,
  nextPage: undefined,
  nextPageAsync: undefined
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: `resultSet.rows[0].id`

Comment: how did you tried to access?